# Dockerfile build takes too long then crashes with craco - either missing tailwindcss module or heap memory

Tags: reactjs, docker, deployment, craco

I am a beginner with Docker and I am trying to prepare and containerise my `react` frontend for a production build in order to deploy it to AWS ECS.

My frontend folder is around 660mb with all its `node_modules` installed and the `node_modules` alone take around 535mb space. The `src` folder is a meager 38mb, yet when I create an image from it, it increases in size to 1gb...

However the major issues are the following:

1. When I run `docker build` it takes a a whopping 40 minutes for a build.
2. Most of the times I get crashes that involve either `heap memory`, running out of memory or it stating that module `tailwindcss` was not found.
3. The other issue I have is that a simple `yarn install` step will take around 1000 seconds when I am running `docker build`.
4. And the image that is built is far too large: 1gb?

I have removed a significant amount of `dependencies` and am currently removing more, but I still don't understand why the `node_modules` grows to such a large size and why it crashes due to memory constantly?

I am currently trying to ensure it is able to run on the free ecs with `512mb` memory, but it does not seem likely that I am able to achieve this.

Is my multi-stage build causing too much memory to be allocated for the creation of the images? What should I look at?

Attached is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS build
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /app
# Installing dependencies first can save time on rebuilds
# We do need the full (dev) dependencies here
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --network-timeout 1000000
# Then copy in the actual sources we need and build
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
WORKDIR /app
# This _only_ builds a runtime node_modules tree.
# We won't need the package.json to actually run the application.
# If you needed developer-oriented tools to do this install they'd
# be isolated to this stage.
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --network-timeout 1000000 --production 

FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules/
COPY --from=build /app/build/ ./build/
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["npx"]
CMD ["serve", "-g", "build"]
```

The `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "stepsapi",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.3",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.3",
    "autoprefixer": "9",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "country-state-city": "2.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "history": "^5.2.0",
    "pigeon-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "postcss": "7",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-big-scheduler": "^0.2.5",
    "react-calendar": "^3.7.0",
    "react-cookies": "^0.1.1",
    "react-dnd": "5.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-flow-renderer": "^9.1.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-s3": "^1.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.5.0",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "three": "0.124.0",
    "tw-elements": "^1.0.0-alpha13",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco  start --openssl-legacy-provider",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false CLIENT_ENV=production craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7"
  }
}
```